# How to create a Set of class in Swift

Tags: swift, swift2

I'm trying to create a class that will define the properties that I need for a Expandable Table View. So I need to have a class that inside I can declare a property that reference to the same class (expandable parent row childs).

Here is the code that I have:

```
public class ExpandableCell
{

    var icon : String
    /// The title for the cell.
    var title: String

    /// The childs of the cell
    var childs: Set<ExpandableCell> = Set<ExpandableCell>()


}
```

But Im getting an error:

[image]

> Any clue on how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two issues here.

1. You need to set default values for your `icon` and `title` variables, or create an initializer to set them when the instance is created, or change them to optionals.
2. Your class must conform to `Hashable` and `Equatable` in order to be used as a type in a `Set`.

Updated code:

```
class ExpandableCell: Hashable, Equatable
{
    var icon : String = ""
    /// The title for the cell.
    var title: String = ""

    /// The childs of the cell
    var childs: Set<ExpandableCell> = Set<ExpandableCell>()

    // MARK: - Hashable
    var hashValue: Int {
        return title.hashValue
    }
}

// MARK: - Equatable
func ==(lhs: ExpandableCell, rhs: ExpandableCell) -> Bool {
    return lhs.title == rhs.title
}
```

Note: This code assumes that two cells are equal if they have the same title. You may want to change that based on your application/use. If so, change the `hashValue` to return a unique `Int` based on whatever makes your cells be considered the same. And update the `func ==()` in a similar manner. You may need to take into account the children for example.